# Query times vary too much between runs

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying out neo4j to work on my grade project and I decided to create a database with the datagen provided by [LDBC](https://github.com/ldbc/ldbc_snb_datagen). This datagen came with [these queries](https://github.com/ldbc/ldbc_snb_implementations/tree/master/cypher/queries).

So I decided to run one of those queries and collected it's execution time (I ran them using cypher-shell command). So I collected these times:

```
    553575, 558724, 556443, 556675, 551304, 555385, 552896
```

**Note:** I took the first run out because as said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482616/neo4j-job-execution-time) the first time seemed to be a spike due to cold-cache.

Everything smooth until here, then I've decided to create some paths with new labels, making the database grow from 1.5GB to 2.4GB. The I decided to run again the queries expecting for them to be slower. For my surprise I saw that the times were substantially smaller.

```
    382331, 380566, 405636, 405953, 407277, 391804, 371134, ....
```

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482616/neo4j-job-execution-time). I expected them to be like all be around a same time (like the first run) and perhaps bigger, but definitely not smaller.

For the purpose of this question, I am using an **AWS machine**, especifically the **i3.4xlarge** instance (16 vCPUs, 122GB RAM and 2x 1.9TB NVMe SSD). The current version I am using of Neo4j is **3.3.5** and I am using [cypher-shell](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/tools/cypher-shell/) as stated above.

Additionally I have no other programs/process running on this machine so I think we can just eliminate that issue (and despite that being the case, it should slow them down, not speed them up).

Thanks in advance, I am just asking to see if someone may shed some light for me on this issue :)

**EDIT:**

The changes I've made were added some paths between :Message nodes and :Person's. Also some between :Person and :Person, some between :TagClass (other label) and :Person. Additionally, the DB had index on :Tag(name), :Person(name), :TagClass(name) and :Country(name) but for the purpose of executing the query, dropped those.

The original query:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (tag:Tag {name: 'Arnold_Schwarzenegger'})
MATCH (tag)<-[:HAS_TAG]-(message1:Message)-[:HAS_CREATOR]->(person1:Person)
MATCH (tag)<-[:HAS_TAG]-(message2:Message)-[:HAS_CREATOR]->(person1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (message2)<-[:LIKES]-(person2:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (person2)<-[:HAS_CREATOR]-(message3:Message)<-[like:LIKES]-(p3:Person)
RETURN
  person1.id,
  count(DISTINCT like) AS authorityScore
ORDER BY
  authorityScore DESC,
  person1.id ASC
LIMIT 100
```

These are profiles from both runs, due to space only added one plan. I can assure you, they're both the exact same (even on db hits, paths expanded, everything):

1st run:

```
| Plan      | Statement   | Version      | Planner | Runtime       | Time   | DbHits | Rows |
| "PROFILE" | "READ_ONLY" | "CYPHER 3.3" | "COST"  | "INTERPRETED" | 556443 | 0      | 100  |
```

2nd:

```
| Plan      | Statement   | Version      | Planner | Runtime       | Time   | DbHits | Rows |
| "PROFILE" | "READ_ONLY" | "CYPHER 3.3" | "COST"  | "INTERPRETED" | 371134 | 0      | 100  |
```

Plan:

```
+----------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator             | Estimated Rows | Rows     | DB Hits   | Cache H/M | Identifiers                                                                                                                   | Other                                                        |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults      |            100 |      100 |         0 |       0/0 | anon[349], anon[355], authorityScore, person1.id                                                                              | 0.0                                                          |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Projection          |            100 |      100 |         0 |       0/0 | anon[349], anon[355], authorityScore, person1.id                                                                              | 0.0; {person1.id : , authorityScore : }                      |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Top                 |            100 |      100 |         0 |       0/0 | anon[349], anon[355]                                                                                                          | 0.0; 100; anon[355], anon[349]                               |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation    |         126593 |     1842 |  49948155 |       0/0 | anon[349], anon[355]                                                                                                          | 0.0; anon[349]                                               |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Apply               |    16025884097 | 49948155 |         0 |       0/0 | person2, anon[219], message3, anon[60], tag, anon[136], p3, message1, anon[167], anon[271], message2, anon[91], person1, like | 0.0                                                          |
| |\                       +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Optional          |           7317 | 49948155 |         0 |       0/0 | person2, message3, p3, anon[271], like                                                                                        | 0.0                                                          |
| | |                      +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Filter            |           5037 | 49897917 |  49897917 |       0/0 | person2, message3, p3, anon[271], like                                                                                        | 0.0; p3:Person                                               |
| | |                      +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)       |           5037 | 49897917 | 108680609 |       0/0 | person2, message3, p3, anon[271], like                                                                                        | 0.0; (message3)<-[like:LIKES]-(p3)                           |
| | |                      +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Filter            |           7028 | 58782692 |  58782692 |       0/0 | anon[271], message3, person2                                                                                                  | 0.0; message3:Message                                        |
| | |                      +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)       |           7028 | 58782692 |  58866898 |       0/0 | anon[271], message3, person2                                                                                                  | 0.0; (person2)<-[anon[271]:HAS_CREATOR]-(message3)           |
| | |                      +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Argument          |           7317 |   130898 |         0 |       0/0 | person2                                                                                                                       | 0.0                                                          |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +OptionalExpand(All) |           7317 |   130898 |    220191 |       0/0 | person2, anon[219], anon[60], tag, anon[136], message1, anon[167], message2, anon[91], person1                                | 0.0; (message2)<-[anon[219]:LIKES]-(person2); person2:Person |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeHashJoin        |           7317 |    51779 |         0 |       0/0 | anon[60], tag, anon[136], message1, anon[167], message2, anon[91], person1                                                    | 0.0; tag, person1                                            |
| |\                       +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Filter            |         341165 |     4241 |      4241 |       0/0 | tag, anon[136], anon[167], message2, person1                                                                                  | 0.0; person1:Person                                          |
| | |                      +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)       |         341165 |     4241 |      8482 |       0/0 | tag, anon[136], anon[167], message2, person1                                                                                  | 0.0; (message2)-[anon[167]:HAS_CREATOR]->(person1)           |
| | |                      +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Filter            |         341165 |     4241 |      4646 |       0/0 | anon[136], message2, tag                                                                                                      | 0.0; message2:Message                                        |
| | |                      +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)       |         372142 |     4646 |      4647 |       0/0 | anon[136], message2, tag                                                                                                      | 0.0; (tag)<-[anon[136]:HAS_TAG]-(message2)                   |
| | |                      +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +Filter            |           1608 |        1 |     16080 |       0/0 | tag                                                                                                                           | 0.0; tag.name = {  AUTOSTRING0}                              |
| | |                      +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +NodeByLabelScan   |          16080 |    16080 |     16081 |       0/0 | tag                                                                                                                           | 0.0; :Tag                                                    |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter              |         341165 |     4241 |      4241 |       0/0 | anon[60], tag, message1, anon[91], person1                                                                                    | 0.0; person1:Person                                          |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)         |         341165 |     4241 |      8482 |       0/0 | anon[60], tag, message1, anon[91], person1                                                                                    | 0.0; (message1)-[anon[91]:HAS_CREATOR]->(person1)            |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter              |         341165 |     4241 |      4646 |       0/0 | anon[60], message1, tag                                                                                                       | 0.0; message1:Message                                        |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)         |         372142 |     4646 |      4647 |       0/0 | anon[60], message1, tag                                                                                                       | 0.0; (tag)<-[anon[60]:HAS_TAG]-(message1)                    |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter              |           1608 |        1 |     16080 |       0/0 | tag                                                                                                                           | 0.0; tag.name = {  AUTOSTRING0}                              |
| |                        +----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan     |          16080 |    16080 |     16081 |       0/0 | tag                                                                                                                           | 0.0; :Tag                                                    |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------    --------------------------------+

... Results ...

100 rows available after 371134 ms, consumed after another 0 ms
```

**Note:** SO Doesn't allow me to write over 30000 characters so had to reduce the text.

Comment: Can you provide, in your question, the exact query you are trying, and also exactly how you changed the DB? In addition, would it be possible for you to provide the [profile](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) of the query with the old DB, and again with the new DB?

Comment: Just added the plan. The same applies for both runs. In both cases they're the third consecutive run (to avoid first or second run spikes due to cold-cache). Also added some of the changes I've made, just created paths between some nodes, but they are all under a new tag (idk if that affects somehow)

Answer (score 0):

The Cypher planner takes the current characteristics of the DB into account when deciding how to carry out a query. Any changes to a DB can alter the execution plan, which can greatly affect the timing.

The best way to understand timing differences after updating a DB is to do before-and-after comparisons of the query [profile](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/). Without knowing what query you are using, and especially without the before-and-after profile information (neither of which were provided), it is difficult to impossible to figure out why the timing changed.

The only guess that can be made, with the little information available, is that the timing had changed because the DB characteristics had changed in ways that caused the planner to alter the execution plan.

Comment: I don't know if it updates you on the post (newb here) but I updated the post :) Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Still not enough information to know in detail how to fix, if possible. But, generally, if you add more `MATCH` patterns and/or make existing patterns more complex, then that will tend to make the query slower and take up more memory -- as one should expect. Even if the Profiles seem to be identical, take a look at the `DB Hits` values -- they are probably very different.

Comment: The DB Hits are exactly the same, for the exact same query. All I did was added some paths. I'll try to add both plans. I didn't changed the query at all, just like stated added some arcs between some nodes. But what I was expecting is slower times, instead, got faster ones.